# Jquery form serialize with parameters

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I made a form with several inputs. If I type one of these inputs it insert a new row to mysql. But if I want to update my sql with every new fielddate it gets lost, because I don't know how to send the data to mysql,

Here are my scripts:

```
<script>

Here I check and post a row to sql if this is the first keyup.

$('.ajax').keyup(function(){
if(document.getElementById("id").value==0){
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    data: { insert: "1" },
    url:location.href,
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(response){
       var id = response.id;
       if(typeof(id) != 'undefined'){
          $('#id').val(id);
       }
    }
  });
document.getElementById("id").value="1";
$("#rejtett1").show();
$("#rejtett2").show();
$("#rejtett3").show();
}
else{

  If not, here I post the form!

    $('#addfelhasznalo').delay(200).submit();
}

});

There I want to update the data to mysql.

$("#addfelhasznalo").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        url: location.href+"?update=1",
        data: $("#addfelhasznalo").serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
                 }
    });
});


</script>

if($_GET["insert"]){

mysql_query("INSERT into accounts() VALUES()");

}

if($_GET["update"]){

mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET ".$_GET["field"]."=".$_GET["fielddata"]." WHERE id='".$_GET["id"]."'");

}
```

Comment: You have serious SQL injection vulnerabilities that you should address.  Also you should really not be using the `mysql_*` functions in PHP which are deprecated.  I would suggest possibly using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. I should also mention that it is traditional, when inserting/updating data, to utilize the POST method, as you typically don't want people to be able to change your data just be adding stuff to a URL.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Yes, what specific problems are you having?  Are you getting errors?  Have you done any basic debugging to try to identify where your problem is?

Comment: How the pass the field names and value with variables like field and fielddata?

Comment: "If not, here I post the form!". Do you really want to post the form, or do you want to make an ajax request? `.submit()` will cause a regular HTML form submission without triggering the 'submit' handler. I rather expect that's why you are having a problem.